# Changing layout using logic

Tags: java

I am having trouble with my calendar project. I currently have all I need and it is complete except that it is in a list rather than set out as a calendar would be. I do not want to use swing or any imports but rather use logic to create a good layout as I am told that this is possible.

My code at the moment is:

```
public static String[] teamJedi = {"Andrew", "Sanjay", "Austen", "Rob"};

    public static String[] daysOfWeek = {"| SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THUR | FRI | SAT |"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(daysOfWeek));

        Calendar calendar = getMonthCalendar(args);


        int month = calendar.get(MONTH);


        // int teamSize = teamJedi.length;

        int counter = findOffSetToStart(teamJedi, args[2]);

        while (calendar.get(MONTH) == month) {
            System.out.println(calendar.getTime());

            if (!isWeekEnd(calendar)) {
                System.out.println(teamJedi[counter++ % 4]);
            }

            calendar.add(DATE, 1);

        }
    }

    private static int findOffSetToStart(String[] teamJedi, String args) {
        return Arrays.asList(teamJedi).indexOf(args);
    }

    private static Calendar getMonthCalendar(String[] args) {

        Calendar calendar = getInstance();

        int year = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        calendar.set(year, month, 1);

        calendar.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(MILLISECOND, 0);


        return calendar;
    }

    private static boolean isWeekEnd(Calendar calendar) {
        return (calendar.get(DAY_OF_WEEK)) == SATURDAY || (calendar.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) == SUNDAY);
    }


}
```

The output of this is a list, so what can I do to get a traditional calendar layout?

Comment: why does the `String` array `daysOfWeek` contain of only one item?

Comment: I thought it would be easier to display at the top of output, if you think different please give me suggestions